# FFMPEG x11grab/pulse AV capture: Non-monotonous DTS

Tags: ffmpeg, screen-capture

I've fiddled with lots of options trying to fix this, but I thought it would be better to start from what I want at the beginning and ask for help. I want to capture some emulated game footage, usually at the resolution of 256*240, so while I'm at it I thought I may as well capture the footage losslessly and without rescaling. I use this command line:

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -i :0.0 -f pulse -i alsa_output.pci-0000_08_00.3.analog-stereo.monitor -ac 2 -c:v libx264rgb -pix_fmt bgr0 -c:a copy -y /tmp/capture.mkv
```

(Incidentally, I use /tmp as a ram disk/tmpfs partition, I'm not sure if that would affect things.)

However, I always run into some kind of timestamp issue, with a warning that looks something like this:

> ```
> [matroska @ 0x55b042f269b0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1;
> previous: 144, current: 141; changing to 144. This may result in
> incorrect timestamps in the output file.
> ```

The resulting video has desynced audio/video, and when played back, the video will randomly freeze, and speed up, with distorted audio which may end up stopping completely partway through playing. Recording video or audio individually work fine, but its when ffmpeg attempts to sync them that issues seem to start appearing.

I've tried all kinds of options from forum posts, particularly on the StackExchange network, but the only one which seemed to be working in the right direction was `-async 1/-af aresample=async=1:min_hard_comp=0.100000:first_pts=0`:

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -i :0.0 -f pulse -i alsa_output.pci-0000_08_00.3.analog-stereo.monitor \
    -ac 2 -c:v libx264rgb -pix_fmt bgr0 -c:a pcm_s16le \
    -af aresample=async=1:min_hard_comp=0.100000:first_pts=0 -y /tmp/capture.mkv
```

This doesn't print any DTS-related warnings, but I actually experience audio/video freezing during gameplay, and the resulting video still isn't great. I doubt it a little bit, but it might be that my hardware just isn't able to deal with the overhead of game emulation, recording, and encoding at the same time. Maybe if it's possible to set both vcodec and acodec to "copy", mux that into a .nut (mkv doesn't like raw video, apparently), and somehow re-sync the video and audio in post, I could confirm if it's that kind of issue.

This question might not be very well put-together, and I'm sorry about that, but I'm at my wit's end. I thought it would be best to post a question myself, starting with my objective, and then a little bit about things I've tried. I'd like to troubleshoot, try different suggestions again, and evaluate whether what I'm trying to do is actually possible with my hardware. That much might be a little too optimistic since most stackexchange questions seem to die if the asker doesn't think their question's been solved within 5 hours and nobody's able to offer anything else.

These are relevant looking specs, according to "neofetch":

```
CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 1600 (12) @ 3.200GHz
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970
Memory: 2910MiB / 16017MiB
```

Comment: Try using `-f alsa` (even with pulseaudio's ALSA emulation) rather than `-f pulse`. I've experienced similar sync problems, and was unable to solve them while using ffmpeg's pulse input, no matter what options I tried, and even with the help of ffmpeg IRC and mailing list. I came to the conclusion that ffmpeg's pulse input is broken.

Comment: Wow! Good on you for answering such an old post. I was a bit too grumpy in that last paragraph. I guess it doesn't technically fix whatever FFMPEG or Pulseaudio might be doing in this particular case, in particular situations, but that's definitely a solution I didn't consider at the time. I've long since uninstalled Pulseaudio personally, but I'm sure it'll help somebody.